# Bitbucket git clone BUG: remote-curl.c:1342: The entire rpc->buf should be larger than LARGE_PACKET_MAX C file error

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, fatal-error, git-clone

**git version 2.26.2**

```
git clone https://my.company.com/bitbucket/scm/common/common-vm-resources.git
```

While running `git clone` on a repository with / without **submoduels**, I'm getting the following error. Using `-v` option for verbose, didn't help.

**BUG: remote-curl.c:1342: The entire rpc->buf should be larger than LARGE_PACKET_MAX**

```
Cloning into 'common-vm-resources'...
BUG: remote-curl.c:1342: The entire rpc->buf should be larger than LARGE_PACKET_MAX
fatal: expected flush after ref listing
```

Comment: Anything starting with `BUG` like this indicates that Git has self-diagnosed a bug in this Git version. Try upgrading your Git, but I note that LARGE_PACKET_MAX itself is unchanged in 8 years and I have not seen any mention of this bug - you might need to report it to the Git mailing list or Git-for-Windows group (depending on which you're using).

Comment: For a workaround, perhaps you can clone with `ssh` instead of `https`.

Comment: The same version works on a different machine and clone using ssh:/ gives the same error. Got the version from local repository (screened/approved)

Comment: An `ssh://...` URL fetch doesn't go through remote-curl.c at all, so it can't possibly trip that particular bug line. Something is very squirrelly here.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the following resolved the issue. The issue was coming because somehow this property (***http.postBuffer***) was set to a very low value i.e. lower number/value that what GIT was expecting to work successfully.

- It directly relates to the available memory on your machine/VM/image as well, so set it accordingly. Try smaller number and increase the value if reqd.

**- Run the following command:**

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```